# Админка DJANGO: выбор родительской категории при смежном хранение дерева каталога

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, django-orm

Прошу умных людей помочь найти варианты решения задачи.

**Задача:** в админке DJANGO сделать удобный наглядный выбор Родительской категории по наименованию из списка существующих категорий.

Есть каталог с древовидной структурой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагается использовать смежный способ хранения дерева в базе данных:

```
ID       NAME            PARENT_ID
1        Диагностика     Null
2        УЗИ             1
3        ЭКГ             1
4        УЗИ сердца      2
5        УЗИ почек       2
```

***Вопросы:***

1. Как сделать выбор Родительской категории по наименованию из существующих категорий?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Нужно ли использовать другой способ хранения в БД, чтобы реализовать выбор Родительской категории из существующих по наименованию?

Comment: вопрос 1 не понятен. хотите чтоб вместо цифры выдавало поле name?

Comment: вопрос 2 : такой способ и используется в интернет-магазинах. в prestashop точно такой

Comment: @JopaBoga, скриншот в 1 вопросе - это модель "Категория". У модели "Категория" поле "Родительская категория" сейчас типа  PositiveSmallInteger, т. е. можно ввести произвольное положительное число. А нужно, чтобы у поля "Родительская категория" был ограниченный **список** значений (наименований существующих категорий). В БД при этом нужно записывать id выбранной родительской категории, чтобы не привязываться к name. Это нужно, чтобы обычный смертный через админку мог легко редактировать дерево каталога. Я себе так это вижу. Есть возможность так сделать? Или есть другие подходы? Не понятно ...